# An error occurred while trying to call the request method lookupSoftwareForBundleId

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, itunes, bundle-identifier

I keep getting this error when I validate my app ,what dose it means?Anyone can help? I'm in a hurry,thanks!

Comment: be more descriptive with your problem. there are many issues related to the validating app, so your vague statement isn't able to pinpoint your problem

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is Apple bug. You can search Twitter for "lookupSoftwareForBundleID" - results are periodical :)

And it just happens to me. I am waiting for solution right now.

Comment: Oh,have you ever run into this before?

Comment: I have sent beta builds today and yesterday and faced problem 20 mins ago :)

Comment: Yeah , it happened to me maybe at the same time.So  do you mean that the only thing we can do is waiting for Apple to fix this?

Comment: @bigCan just successfully submitted my beta. Without any changes from my side.